# Make two divs side by side where one has position fixed

Tags: html, css

So I have two divs like this

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child1"/>
  <div class="child2"/>
</div>
```

child1 is position: fixed, and I want child2 and child1 to be side by side.

I've tried using inline-block, but that doesn't work. What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

Enclose the elements that should be fixed in a container, set that container to `position:fixed`, and position its children accordingly. Perhaps with `float:left` and `float:right`.

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="fixed-container">
      <div class="child1"/>
      <div class="child2"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/ozejet/2/edit)

```
.child1 {
  position:fixed;
}
.child2{
  float:right;
  margin-right:350px;
}
```

[May be it could be help you](http://jsfiddle.net/XF8rA/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Once you put something 'fixed' it's out of the flow so you can absolutely position child 2 but it will move relative to the container it's in